# Linker error during .so file creation. Error: Function not Implemented

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, ld, clang++

During the linking stage for an `“.so”` file creation, an error message is being flagged by the `“ld”` linker.

I tried to search around it but couldn’t get anything concrete. This message is getting flagged with
the `“--trace”` linker flag enabled. `“--trace”` dumps the files used in the course of the linking step. The platform is `Windows`.

Below mentioned is the error msg. There are multiple occurrence of this message during the linking process.
Any leads would be appreciated.

ERROR:

```
arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: error: dummy.so: write: Function not implemented**
```

Comment: In my case it happened on 32-bit target  with NDK19c when we added to much code to the project and the resulting .so size went over 2GB. lld generates smaller binaries maybe that's why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Also ran into this issue recently and it also only happens on Windows when doing a debug build.  I was never able to figure out a code fix to make the LD linker happy and resolve the errors.

However, I was able to switch to using the LLD LLVM linker and get a debug build working again on Windows.  After switching, the LLD linker uncovered some linker errors that LD never seemed to detect.  After fixing those issues I was able to build successfully again.

To switch to using the LLD linker, I added the following linker flags to my build:

```
-fuse-ld=lld
-Wl,--no-threads
```

The LLD linker was made available in NDK r18 so you'll need to build using a suitable NDK otherwise the flags will not be recognized.

I am using CMake so I just added these flags at the end of my target_link_libraries declaration on my shared library.

I added the second flag, "-Wl,--no-threads", to disable multithreaded linking which apparently can be an issue on Windows and cause it to hang (see https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r19 for more info).

If you're using ndk-build then multithreaded linking is should already disabled by default (as of NDK r19b).

NOTE: I am currently building with NDK r19c.  Eventually, the Android NDK will switch to the LLD LLVM linker by default (estimated r21).